# CALayer Hides the UILabel above the UIView

Tags: swift

I have a `UIView` with a `CAGradientLayer`, but the labels in the `UIView` don't appear when i launch the app.

```
@IBOutlet weak var CardView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var CardTiltle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var CardInfo: UILabel!

func prepareCardViewUI() {

    let GradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    GradientLayer.frame = CardView.bounds
    GradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(red: 254/255, green: 164/255, blue: 156/255, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 207/255, blue: 170/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
    GradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    GradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1.0)
    GradientLayer.cornerRadius = 25


    CardView.layer.addSublayer(GradientLayer)
    CardView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
}
```

Comment: where you are using func prepareCardViewUI() in viewdidLoad ?

Comment: Did my answer works for you?

Comment: yes in ViewDidLoad()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line `CardView.layer.addSublayer(GradientLayer)` with below line:

```
CardView.layer.insertSublayer(GradientLayer, at: 0)
```

Hope this will work for you.

[image]